# Retracting close vote does not refresh tally

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes

When we vote to close a question, the vote tally automatically updates, as well as giving us a popup saying that our vote has now been recorded.

When we retract a close vote, however, a popup still comes up saying that our vote was retracted, but the tally does not refresh. Refreshing the page yields the updated tally though. Although this might not be a serious bug, it sometimes is assuring to have that vote tally decrease - it can be confusing to have retracted a vote but not having the tally decrease.

Comment: maybe if you didn't have so much volatility in your close-voting habits... bah-dum-chhhh

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'd +1 you, but my comment bots ran out for the day -_-

Comment: @Cole if I +1 your comment expressing a desire to +1 my comment, will the world implode?

Comment: @AndrewBarber I guess not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in revision  2013.7.22.1253 (meta) and  2013.7.22.877 (sites), the count is now updated after the close vote is retracted.