# Can't retract close vote when revisiting post on mobile site, and other inconsistencies

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, mobile-web, retracted-close-votes

Summary of issues:

1. Can't retract close vote on mobile after a page refresh
2. Voting to close on mobile shows `close 1` and then when page refreshes it shows `close (1)`
3. Retracting vote on mobile doesn't refresh tally -- continues to show `close 1` instead of just `close`, until you refresh

I voted to close a question on my desktop. Later on my phone I decided to retract this vote, but I couldn't. I saw `close (1)` but it was grayed out. Switching to "full site" allowed me to retract my vote.

In trying to reproduce, I went to a post on phone and voted to close a question. The text changed to `close 1`. I could retract my vote at this time, and doing so, the text stayed the same as `close 1` which seems to contradict [Retracting close vote does not refresh tally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189757/retracting-close-vote-does-not-refresh-tally).  Refreshing page showed correct `close` text grayed out.

Another attempt on phone, I voted to close a question. The text changed to `close 1`. I refreshed the page and could no longer retract my vote as the text said `close (1)` and was grayed out.

Visiting question with existing close votes showed `close 2`. I also voted to close and then it said `close 3`. Refreshing page showed `closed (3)` grayed out.